# Printing list in different columns

Tags: python-3.x

I am quite new to Python and I am now struggling with printing my list in columns. It prints my lists in one columns only but I want it printed under 4 different titles. I know am missing something but can't seem to figure it out. Any advice would be really appreciated!

```
def createMyList():
    myAgegroup = ['20 - 39','40 - 59','60 - 79']
    mygroupTitle = ['Age','Underweight','Healthy','Overweight',]
    myStatistics = [['Less than 21%','21 - 33','Greater than 33%',],['Less than 23%','23 - 35','Greater than 35%',],['Less than 25%','25 - 38','Greater than 38%',]]
    printmyLists(myAgegroup,mygroupTitle,myStatistics)
    return

def printmyLists(myAgegroup,mygroupTitle,myStatistics):
    print(':    Age    :    Underweight    :    Healthy    :    Overweight    :')

    for count in range(0, len(myAgegroup)):
        print(myAgegroup[count])

    for count in range(0, len(mygroupTitle)):
        print(mygroupTitle[count])

    for count in range(0, len(myStatistics)):
        print(myStatistics[0][count])
        return

createMyList()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you show your desired output? It looks like there's 4 headers but only 2-3(?) columns. Where is the data coming from--is it dynamically generated? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To print data in nice columns is nice to know Format Specification Mini-Languag ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)). Also, to group data together, look at `zip()` builtin function ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip)).

Example:

```
def createMyList():
    myAgegroup = ['20 - 39','40 - 59','60 - 79']
    mygroupTitle = ['Age', 'Underweight','Healthy','Overweight',]
    myStatistics = [['Less than 21%','21 - 33','Greater than 33%',],['Less than 23%','23 - 35','Greater than 35%',],['Less than 25%','25 - 38','Greater than 38%',]]
    printmyLists(myAgegroup,mygroupTitle,myStatistics)

def printmyLists(myAgegroup,mygroupTitle,myStatistics):

    # print the header:
    for title in mygroupTitle:
        print('{:^20}'.format(title), end='')

    print()

    # print the columns:
    for age, stats in zip(myAgegroup, myStatistics):
        print('{:^20}'.format(age), end='')
        for stat in stats:
            print('{:^20}'.format(stat), end='')
        print()

createMyList()
```

Prints:

```
    Age             Underweight           Healthy            Overweight     
  20 - 39          Less than 21%          21 - 33         Greater than 33%  
  40 - 59          Less than 23%          23 - 35         Greater than 35%  
  60 - 79          Less than 25%          25 - 38         Greater than 38%
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Am wondering why my code didn't work though? I did try another method as well but was hoping to figure out why my code didn't work.

Comment: This is a bit advance for me so was trying to keep it simple and understand the functions I was working with.

Comment: @Daniel As a start, your code isn't working because `print()` function prints every value on separate line. Try to put `end=''` parameter in the `print()` functions, then they will print values in row - experiment with it...